# Syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

В чём может быть моя ошибка?

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {
private $conn;

 public function connect ()
 {

       require_once 'config.php'

      //Строка ниже подсвечена ошибкой 
       $this->conn = new mysqli(host:DB_HOST, username:DB_USER, passwd:DB_PASSWORD, dbname:DB_DATEBASE);
       return $this->conn;
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: см. предыдущую строку кода. Довольно очевидная синтаксическая ошибка там.

Comment: @Мелкий Спасибо за совет. Точку с запятой пропустил..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы забыли запятую после require_once
2. Не надо делать return вы уже обращаетесь к переменной $conn
3. При подключение mysqli не надо писать 'host:' , 'username:' ...
   Это делается при подключение PDO
   вот код

   ```
   <?php
   class DB_Connect {
   private $conn;

   public function connect ()
   {

       require_once 'config.php';
       $this->conn = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'db');
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```